# How to add fallback to touchable wrapper in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is a [`<Touchable />`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-platform-touchable) component, which wraps `<TouchableNativeFeedback>` and its fallbacks for iOS or older android versions.

In its docs there is a `fallback` property:

> fallback - If TouchableNativeFeedback is not available (on iOS and on Android API <= 20 / Android < 5.0), the component specified in this prop is used instead. Defaults to TouchableOpacity.

Usually `<TouchableOpacity />` is a good approach as fallback, but sometimes I want to adapt the iOS defaults and use `<TouchableHighlight />` instead. **How can I do this?**

I have tried to add `<Touchable fallback="TouchableHighlight" />` which results in a *Invariant Violation: View config not found for name TouchableHighlight*. Although I have tried to add something like `fallback={<TouchableHighlight />}` which does not work neither.

I appreciate any help to understand this. Maybe [the components code is useful](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-platform-touchable/blob/master/PlatformTouchable.js) as well, as its a pretty short and straight forward component.

Answer (score 0):

That library doesn't give you the option to use `TouchableHighlight`, you can either create your own component or fork the library and add it in. It seems like all you have to do is import it at the top.

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-platform-touchable/blob/master/PlatformTouchable.js

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the suggestion. Sadly its not only TouchableHighlight not working. For example the already imported `TouchableOpacity` does not work neither.